# how to create array with n number of bytes?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, enumerable

How to create `byte[] digits;` with n number of bytes?

I know I can do `Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToArray();` but this creates an int[]. Is there a way to create a byte[]?

My priority is a fast performance. Keeping this in mind, is there a faster way (with slightly more code) that can create this?

Comment: Why do you believe that byte[] will give better performance than int[] on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: I don't, byte is just big enough for the digits I want to store :) I don't think it affects performance.

Comment: @JonSkeet No, `Enumerable.Range(1, n)` yields `n` elements.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Doh, doh, doh. I'm stupid. Removing comment.

Comment: @user1933169: It's entirely possible that using a `byte` array will actually be *slower* than using an `int` array depending on what you do with it. It sounds like you're *heavily* micro-optimizing - do you have *any* evidence that this part of your code is actually a bottleneck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with just creating a byte array instance?

```
byte[] digits = new byte[n];
```

And if you want to initialize with values from 1 to n, then I think:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   digits[i-1] = (byte)i; // index is 0-based
```

Will also get you the desired result as fast as possible. Of course, where n < 256!

Comment: Well, looks like I'm the most stupid person in the world today. Thank you sir

Comment: No need to feel stupid. Sometimes the most obvious of things elude us!

Comment: Well, I'm even more stupid then that. I ment, how do I fill the array with digits. ranging from 1->n?

Comment: @user1933169 So you didn't mean to initialize the array elements to `1, 2, 3, 4, ...`?

Comment: It won't fail on `i == n` because the assignment is to `digits[i-1]`.  It does look a bit scary, though.  My preference would be `digits[i] = (byte)i+1;` and have the usual `i < n` in the `for` loop test, but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 11):

If you really like LINQ, you can do

```
byte[] digits = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
```

There's also the possibility

```
byte[] digits = new byte[n];
for (byte b = 1; b <= n; ++b)
    digits[b - 1] = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

To just create a byte array and fill it with bytes 1 to n, you'd just create the array and use a loop:

```
byte[] digits = new byte[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    digits[i] = (byte) (i + 1);
}
```

Note that then `digits[0]` will be 1 etc... is that what you wanted?

However, if your reason for storing these values as bytes is purely performance, you're *probably* micro-optimizing. What are your performance goals? If you use an `int[]` instead, does that miss them? What is the *natural* type for this data? What are you using it for?

Comment: Have to agree w/@Jon about the possibility of micro-optimizing.  Unless they have to be 8 bit values for some reason (well, technically CHAR_BIT-bit values), you might want to take a look at `intfast_t` and the like.  As for performance, note that a typical definition of `uint_fast8_t` is `typedef unsigned int`.

Comment: @frasnian: I think you may have missed the C# context here... No intfast_t etc in this case.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I did completely miss that.  That's what getting up early on a Saturday will get you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like  this :

```
byte[] digits=new byte[2024];
```